# How to construct an element using two Xpath's - WebdriverIO

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, element, webdriver-io

i am new to WebdriverIO and trying to locate an element by combining two xpath's but not sure of the proper syntax or methods. 
say we have a list of user blocks on the page, i want to locate the whole block that contains all the users, i plan on using the '$$' for that so i can pick which user i want to perform action on. then that user block has multiple action options within it so each action has a different path.

Example:

```
var user = browser.$$('//*[@id="react-root-node"]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div');

var userAction = browser.$('div[1]/div[2]/div[1]');
```

what kind of syntax or method can i use to add the second part of the xpath to the first one and have a single element at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can use chain of `$` and `$$`, like:

```
var users = $$('//*[@id="react-root-node"]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div');

// the 1st user in list
users[0].$('./div[1]/div[2]/div[1]')

// the 2st user in list
users[1].$('./div[1]/div[2]/div[1]')
```

More detail can get from [here](http://webdriver.io/api/utility/$.html)

Comment: Thanks. dot is required